# error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:......o/pem/pem_lib.c:637:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Tags: bash, openssl, ssl-certificate

We were able to connect but its not fetching the cert details

```
$ bash-3.2# echo | openssl s_client -host $h -port $p 2>/dev/null

CONNECTED(00000005)

$
```

Any idea why its not fetching the cert details.

Comment: There's a disconnect between the error in the title and the output you provide in the body of the question. Please improve this question. (1) Add the host details. (2) Add the full output. (3) Show where ***`error:0906D06C:PEM routines...`*** comes from.

Comment: *`openssl errstr 0x0906D06C`* tells me *`error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
openssl s_client -connect hostname:443 -servername hostname 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate
```